# CakePHP 2.0.3 Fatal Error flash() on object

Tags: cakephp, fatal-error, cakephp-2.0

I've get this message when I tried to use a wrong controller and I figured it out that I'm not getting the right Error from cakephp I've got in 2.0.0 the right one:

Now when I try a wrong controller I get only this message:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function Flash() on a non-object in
/srv/www/htdocs/web843/HTML/schaetzmal/lib/Cake/View/Layouts/default.ctp
on line 44
```

Does cakephp 2.0.3 have an bug or do I miss something to install to let work this or something else what I can do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you've added the Session helper to your public `$helpers` array.

```
class SomethingsController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Session');
}
```

Or you could add it to [a global AppController](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#the-app-controller) so that the Session helper is available to all controllers.

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $helpers = array('Session');
}
```

Comment: yes it works can´t understand it because i do not use any session and im called an non existing controller what changed in cakepp 2.0.3 that i need to include session helper

Comment: flash() is a method of the SessionHelper. Session handling is done via the SessionComponent, which you don't have to include to use flash messages, I believe.

Comment: sry for my english you did understand me wrong. I call a "non existing controller" and then i got this message. I call as an example: "http://example.com/kkkk" and then i get the fatal error message which is wrong. but when i do what you say to in include session helper then it works fine but don´t understand it

Answer (score 0):

I found some problems why my AppController didn´t work.

Like mensch says i have to use Session in my `AppController` for global but that´s not the solution because the book of cakephp says in "[a global AppController](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#the-app-controller)"

> **NOTE**
> CakePHP merges the following variables from the AppController to your application’s controllers:
>
> - $components
> - $helpers
> - $uses

but it´s not happening. Because i overwrite it in the public variable `$helpers`.
therfore i take the parent given one and merge it with it:

```
<?

class AppController extends Controller {
    
    public $viewClass   = 'Theme';
    public $theme;
    
    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->theme = 'SM';
        $this->helpers = array('Form','Html','Js');
    }
    
}

?>
```

the `$this->helpers = array('Form','Html','Js');` do the merge and it works fine.
thank you guys

thanks for helping mensch that was the hack i needed